# How to disable XPM on Live Target with SDL web 8.1.1 Business type

Tags: dxa

We are not able to find any settings by which we can disable XPM from content published only to Live target, We are using SDL web 8.1.1 + DXA 1.4 default templates to render pages and components.

Moreover we have setup targets staging/live using Business Type and using topology manager.

Please help.

Thanks
Piyush Jain

Comment: XPM will be enabled if the target you're publishing to has the capabilities needed. This is done by the Topology Manager "asking" the discovery service if the current target supports it. In other words, if you don't have the XPM related capabilities in Live (Session Preview Service, Session-Enabled content service) then you will not have XPM in that target.

Answer (score 7):

As Nuno mentioned, SDL Web 8 in general uses the presence of the Preview Service Capability in the CD Environment (Discovery Service) to determine if it is XPM-enabled or not.

DXA automatically suppresses XPM markup on a CD Environment which is not XPM-enabled (i.e. has no Preview Service Capability).

Comment: We have removed the preview capability  configured in discovery service and register discovery service again, But still XPM button and in page source XPM tags are appearing on Live target site.  Please confirm if we need to do any additional settings to make it work.

Comment: How did you "register discovery service again"? Did you get a confirmation that the Preview Capability was removed?

Comment: This is Resolved now, Earlier we are updating discovery registration with command "Java -jar discovery-registration.jar update ", But if we want to remove any existing capability then we we should use command "Java -jar discovery-registration.jar forceSync" instead.  Thanks Rick